# How to use math.stackprinter?

Tags: discussion, export

The website: http://www.stackprinter.com/ is used to print. It needs "Question id ". What is the Question id? I tried, for example, to put [A locally metrizable space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325355/a-locally-metrizable-space) in, however, it always failed. Could somebody help me? Thanks ahead:)

Comment: Like this? http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=327260&service=math.stackexchange

Comment: For that question you should put in the search line: 325355, which is that question's id.

Comment: @DennisGulko: yes.

Comment: @DennisGulko: however it showed:Not found!

Comment: Select "Mathematics" in the drop-down menu...

Comment: yes. I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summarizing my comments: In order to print a question from [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) using [stackprinter](http://www.stackprinter.com/), select "Mathematics" in the drop-down menu and fill the question id (the number following question/ in the question's web-address) in the search area. For example, for the question [A locally metrizable space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325355/a-locally-metrizable-space), fill '325355'.
To print this question - select "Mathematics Meta" in the drop-down menu and fill '8748' :-)

Answer (score 1):

Notice the URL where it says `meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8748/how-to-use-math-stackprinter`. The number after `/questions/` is the key number which is your unique question ID.